# My firefox UI is broken after upgrading to 4.0 - what have I done wrong, how can I fix it?

Tags: upgrade, user-interface, firefox

My FireFox is looking really really ugly since upgrading to 4.0 (definitely not how it's supposed to be looking), see screenshot below.

I had FF 4 RC installed earlier (which looked exactly the same, but I thought it was because it is a release candidate).

Un- and reinstalling firefox did not do the trick, I also tried disabling all add-ons. There is not other theme than the default (4.0) theme installed.

I know that deleting all Firefox stuff from "Documents and Settings" would probably help, but I would rather keep my firefox configuration/preferences etc, so if anyone can give me a clue what I can do about it, I would be very happy.

[image]

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Just out of interest: you have removed the hello/thanks/goodbye parts of my question. Are things like these deprecated here?

Comment: What does it do when you create a new profile? (Launch `firefox.exe -ProfileManager`) Does it restore the UI for the new one?

Comment: @Peter Greetings and thanks, as well as signatures are unnecessary and detract from actual content. On our "meta" site we discuss topics related to SU, [here's a response from a moderator on that topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1318/editing-others-posts-guidelines-etiquette/1319#1319).

Comment: @M'vy Doesn't help, unfortunately, the UI looks exactly the same for the new profile.

Comment: @Daniel Beck ACK :)

Comment: Thanks to Rumen's answer below, the tabs are in place now. However I still did not manage to get rid of the ugly navigation buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also go to Add-ons (Ctrl-Shift-A), Appearance section, and verify that the Default 4.0 theme exists and is the current one.

You may also follow the advice in [Corrupt localstore.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Corrupt_localstore.rdf) of starting Firefox in Safe mode, select the option "Reset toolbars and controls" and click "Make Changes and Restart" :

[image]

It would be interesting to know if in Safe mode the icons are still broken. If not, then this is an add-on problem.

If this doesn't work, you may close Firefox, rename the file localstore.rdf, and let Firefox rebuild it. Be careful not to touch the Firefox installation folder.

Comment: Yes - Default 4.0 is the only theme present.

Comment: Added one more possibility above.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot - The "Safe Mode" option did the trick, the icons are fixed now. I did not know about Safe Mode, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to View -> Toolbars, check "Tabs on Top" and uncheck "Menu Bar". This should bring the new UI style.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixes at least part of the problem :) Now, just the buttons still look ugly as hell, but it is far better now.